# Matlab: SNR of a known signal

Tags: matlab, wav, noise

I have 2 wav files with the same audio but one of them has added noise on it. I want to calculate the SNR of the noisy wav. I know the original noiseless signal but how can i find the noise vector so i can calculate the SNR? Or is there some other way to calculate it?

Comment: Did you try subtracting the noise-free signal from the noisy signal to obtain the noise signal?

Comment: Yes, but i am getting the same noissy audio instead of noise.

Comment: Are you sure that the noised signal is exactly the initial signal + noise?